# Firebase functions - iterate entries and send notification for certain conditions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to use the Firebase functions tool to iterate all the entries of a certain key and send notifications for the relevant users?
Our database looks as follows:

```
"Jobs" : {
    "066802368bd24eab86281df1927df508" : {
      "dates" : [ {
        "date" : 12,
        "day" : 0,
        "hours" : 17,
        "minutes" : 38,
        "month" : 4,
        "seconds" : 54,
        "time" : 61484283534357,
        "timezoneOffset" : -120,
        "year" : 2018
      } ],
      "duration" : "60",
      "jobBidds" : [ {
        "bid" : 552,
        "date" : {
          "date" : 12,
          "day" : 0,
          "hours" : 17,
          "minutes" : 38,
          "month" : 4,
          "seconds" : 54,
          "time" : 61484283534357,
          "timezoneOffset" : -120,
          "year" : 2018
        },
        "myJobId" : "066802368bd24eab86281df1927df508",
        "myPersonId" : "gAUhdaihH1VFUReTKTjjJtVQV112",
        "personId" : "gAUhdaihH1VFUReTKTjjJtVQV112"
      }, {
        "bid" : 56,
        "date" : {
          "date" : 12,
          "day" : 0,
          "hours" : 17,
          "minutes" : 38,
          "month" : 4,
          "seconds" : 54,
          "time" : 61484283534357,
          "timezoneOffset" : -120,
          "year" : 2018
        },
        "myJobId" : "066802368bd24eab86281df1927df508",
        "myPersonId" : "gAUhdaihH1VFUReTKTjjJtVQV112",
        "personId" : "gAUhdaihH1VFUReTKTjjJtVQV112"
      } ],
      "jobCategory" : "סטטיסטיקה",
      "jobImageURL" : "default",
      "jobLatLang" : {
        "latitude" : 32.106922499999996,
        "longitude" : 34.80368359375002
      },
      "jobType" : "PRIVATELESSONS",
      "myDetails" : "",
      "personUid" : "gAUhdaihH1VFUReTKTjjJtVQV112",
      "phoneNumber" : "865"
    },
    "4fdeb7dbfc5c423591df0144d9316f63" : {         etc
```

where each 'job' has a date related to it.
We want the server to somehow iterate through all the jobs, and if the date(for a specific job) has passed, the server will send a notification to the  "myPersonId" notifying him.
Is it possible to set timestamps for a function(i.e tell firebase to run function X every 10 minutes)?
Is there a way to set the notification sent to the user to open a specific activity in android(user-side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find hereafter links to tutorials or code examples covering your needs :

1/To call a Cloud Function regularly, you have to trigger it via http through a cron-job.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA

2/ For sending a notification:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/developer-motivator/functions/index.js

https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4

PS: an extra advice : you should better store your dates as one String if possible. The best option being to convert your date to the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

My team faced a similar situation and we made use of a simple setInterval at index.js.

Have a callback that does the notificiation function.

Also agree to Renaud's point of making use of a better timestamp. We made use of **firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP** as this will take the server time and not the local time of the user. Hope it helps. ATB.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue