# Using Cloud Functions to query Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The Context

I have an React Native event app that sends outs reminders a day before the Booking. 
I have chosen to use cloud functions to query the firestore database and then send out notifications with Cloud Messaging.

The Booking Model
   Title : string,
   StartDate : string  ("2019-03-07"),
   NotificationToken : string

The Problem

My cloud function is doesn't return any events.

This is what I have so far. For now, I am returning the bookings to the browser but I intend to pass it to sendNotifications

```
exports.getBookings = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

        var bookings = db.collection("Bookings")
        .get()
        .then((result) => {

        var bookingList = [];
        result.forEach((element) => {
            bookingList.push(element);
        });
        return bookingList;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error", err);

        return err;
    })
    // sendNotificiation(bookings);
    res.send(bookings);
    })
})
```

This is the event message from Firebase

```
Function execution took 13 ms, finished with status code: 304
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853518/firebase-functions-iterate-entries-and-send-notification-for-certain-condition/49854689#49854689. In addition, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec . The Firebase videos solved it!